# Understanding Component Communication using SubjectBehaviour

Tags: rxjs

I am watching this video on RxJs Subjects.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DvnzeCfYg0s.

When the form is submitted ,i understand that the subject's refreshneeded$ 
next method is called.

I am given to understand though that the chotchkies-list.component is rendered only once using its ngOninit method.

But in this particular case it looks like when the form is submitted 
the subjects next method is called.

But how does calling the next method on refreshneeded$ subject in turn trigger the ngOninit of the chotchkies-list.component ?

Ahh yes and here is the github code

https://github.com/krimple/rxjs-playground

Comment: You want us to watch that video? Please add the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then your question is about a very central concept in how Rxjs works.

When you subscribe to an Observable, like it is done in the ngOnInit, you are saying that you want this code to run every time a new value is emitted by this observable. This is a key concept of Rxjs and observables.

It is also the difference between imperative and reactive programming. When you program imperativly (the most common way), then the place in your code where an event happens need to know what functions to call next. But with observables we are programming reactively, here we can say that this code should react to some event, and the event itself does not need to know what function to call.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense so what you are saying is when the observable emits a new value if i place it in any function be it in ngOninit or a function foo that function will be executed automatically ?

Comment: whole ngOnInit() method is not executed, only the method inside subscribe will be executed if a new value is emitted.

Comment: Yes, but with a clarification: the code that is nested inside the ".pipe()" and ".subscribe()" will be executed. Not the entire outer function itself (the ngOnInit() in our example).

Comment: Aka what @emkay just said